# Can we cut and rotate a particular region of a hyperbolic 3-manifold to get another (non-homeomorphic) hyperbolic 3-manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, manifolds

I'm trying to learn more about hyperbolic 3-manifolds, in particular the geometric implications of doing hyperbolic Dehn surgery to suitable knot complements.

Following this paper by Christian Millichap ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1042 ), we can construct a hyperbolic Montesinos knot $K$ with several tangle regions (see p. 8). We then mutate these tangle regions along a suitable Conway sphere, before doing hyperbolic Dehn surgery to fill up the knot complements. Because of how we constructed the hyperbolic Montesinos  knot $K$ (in particular, the relevant pair of $S^0$'s are unlinked on $K$, see [What does it mean exactly for a pair of $S^0$'s to be unlinked on a knot $K$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289833/what-does-it-mean-exactly-for-a-pair-of-s0s-to-be-unlinked-on-a-knot-k)), it can be shown that $K$ and all its mutations yield a hyperbolic 3-manifold with the same volume. Further, by an argument in this paper I don't fully understand (for details, see the proof of Theorem 3 on pg. 11), we can pick appropriate coefficients for the Dehn surgery so that the hyperbolic manifolds resulting from $K$ and its mutations are all non-homeomorphic.

I want to have a more precise (and concrete) understanding of how "different" these hyperbolic 3-manifolds are, beyond the fact that they are non-homeomorphic. In particular, suppose we have a hyperbolic knot $K$ and its mutant $K'$ and we know that they yield non-homeomorphic hyperbolic 3-manifolds (call them $M_{K}$ and $M_{K'}$) with the same finite volume via Dehn surgery.

My question is: since mutations of knots involve "cutting up" a certain region of a knot and rotating it appropriately to get a different knot, is it possible for us to cut out an analogous region of $M_{K}$ and (via some isometry in $H^3$) "rotate" the region to obtain $M_{K'}$?

In particular, I don't understand the geometric aspects of hyperbolic Dehn surgery well enough to know if filling in the knot complement with a solid torus presents an obstruction to this. All I know is that hyperbolic Dehn surgery involves picking a suitable pair of integers $(p,q)$ and choosing a basis $(m,l)$ for the fundamental group of the torus boundary of the knot complement (where m and l corresponds to the meridional and longitudinal side of the torus respectively). We may interpret the knot complement as a hyperbolic 3-manifold with a cusp corresponding to the torus boundary; via hyperbolic Dehn surgery, we can cut off the cusp and glue in a solid torus by mapping the boundary of the meridian disc of the torus to $s=pm+ql$ where $s$ is a slope on the torus boundary of the knot complement. (I am following p. 7 of the Millichap paper here).  From a geometric standpoint, all I take from this is that there is a very specific way of gluing the solid torus along the torus boundary of the knot complement, and this might give us problems if we were to "cut and paste" the region in order to get a new hyperbolic 3-manifold. Am I right about this?

---

If it helps to have something more visual, consider the following two knots, which are the prime Kinoshita-Teraska knot (LH) and the prime Conway knot (RH). This diagram shows how the two are related by a mutation along the Conway sphere (marked in red) by rotation about the y-axis.

[image: The prime Kinoshita–Terasaka knot (11n42) and the prime Conway knot (11n34) respectively, and how they are related by mutation.]

As Ian Agol mentions below, it can be verified that this example of knot mutation satisfies the unlinking condition mentioned above, hence Dehn surgery on the knot complements of these two knots yield hyperbolic 3-manifolds with equal volume. Now, suppose we have filled the knot complements out via Dehn surgery and gotten two non-homeomorphic 3-manifolds with the same volume - can we then cut and rotate whatever is analogous to the red region in the hyperbolic 3-manifold (derived from the LH knot) to get the hyperbolic 3-manifold derived from the RH knot?

Comment: The name is **Montesinos.**

Answer (score 8):

Look at the proof of Theorem 5.5 in [Ruberman's paper.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01389038) The way that he proves that the Dehn fillings on mutants have the same volume is to show that there is a closed genus $\leq 2$ surface on which one may perform mutation, which preserves volume. This surface is obtained from the 4-punctured sphere by tubing along annuli which are tubular neighborhoods of the arcs of the knot lying to one side and whose endpoints are flipped by the mutation. The mutation on the 4-punctured sphere is compatible with mutation on the tubed genus 2 surface, in the sense that mutation along the 4-punctured sphere gives the same manifold as mutation along the genus 2 surface. Hence after Dehn filling, there will still be a mutation along a genus 2 surface which relates the two Dehn fillings.

The examples in your picture do satisfy the unlinking condition (Definition 5.4) which is needed in the hypothesis of Theorem 5.5. 
Here's a picture of the tubed genus 2 surface:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying - I really appreciate it!
I'm aware of Ruberman's paper and of the Theorem, but I'm not sure how the proof relates to the last sentence of your first paragraph. Could you say a little more? I think I understand what you mean by mutation on the 4-punctured sphere being compatible with mutation on a tubed genus 2 surface, but I don't see how this implies that mutation "commutes" with Dehn filling, i.e. mutating the knot $K$ and performing Dehn surgery gives us the same manifold $M$ as performing Dehn surgery on $K$ and "mutating" (?) the hyperbolic 3-manifold.

Comment: In order for these operations to "commute", mutation has to be well-defined on the 3-manifold and I'm not sure what operation you are referring to here. Also, I'm not sure why exchanging mutation and Dehn filling would yield the same manifold. In particular, note that mutating a knot just involves changing a particular region of the (2-dimensional) knot, whereas mutation of the hyperbolic 3-manifold would affect not only the torus boundary of the knot complement (which is defined by the knot) but also the solid torus that has been filled inside this knot complement via Dehn surgery

Comment: My concern is that while I can see how by naive rotation, one may move from one 3-manifold to another so that the torus boundary defined by the knot "lines up", I'm not sure if the solid torus filled inside via Dehn surgery will "line up", especially if Dehn surgery depends on the orientation of the knot.

Comment: Sorry, I think I see the issue - the automorphism of the closed surface is not mutation (ie not the central involution). Nevertheless, it should preserve the geometric structure. I'll modify my answer later.

Comment: Thanks! I've re-read Ruberman's paper more carefully (in particular, Theorem 1.3) and I realised that the automorphism you described is in fact well-defined, and takes hyperbolic manifolds to hyperbolic manifolds. However, the main wrinkle is that this is not enough to establish that the operations "commute". Let $M_{K^{*}}$ be the manifold derived by cut-and-pasting the relevant surface in $M_{K}$, rotated in the obvious way. Then, while the torus boundary shape of $M_{K^{*}}$ and $M_{K'}$ maybe the same, we don't know if the geometric structure of the solid torus filled inside is the same.

Comment: scratch my last comment - I was confused about which side the tubing was occurring. If we tube to the inside, then the involution does not extend to mutation. Extending to the outside along the arcs whose endpoints are preserved by mutation does extend to a mutation of the genus 2 surface.

Comment: Hmm... I think there's some confusion here. I accept that regardless of whether we mutate the knot $K$ on the 4-punctured sphere or on the genus 2 surface, we still get the same manifold after Dehn filling. However, this does not imply that if we were to Dehn fill knot complement of $K$ and then genus 2 mutate, we would get the same manifold had we genus 2 mutated the knot $K$ first before Dehn filling. You may indeed perform the same genus 2 mutation on the Dehn filled solid torus as you did on the original knot (before Dehn filling), but this does not necessarily yield the same manifold.

Comment: This is because the former mutation affects the geometric structure of the Dehn filled solid torus whereas the latter mutation does not - the latter only affects the structure of the knot. The two resulting manifolds would be related insofar as they share the same "cusp" structure (as Ruberman remarks immediately after Lemma 5.3, before Thm 5.5), which is enough to get the result that the manifolds share the same volume; however, I don't see how this is enough to demonstrate that they are indeed the same manifold.

Comment: @asldjk: I don't quite understand your comments. Maybe think about it like this: we have two knots that differ by a mutation on a closed genus 2 surface. Then Dehn fillings will give manifolds that differ by mutation on a genus 2 closed surface. I formulated this originally as something like filling disjoint manifolds is a commutative operation, but I guess you didn't understand that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Yes, I agree that we have two knots that differ by a mutation on a closed genus 2 surface. What I don't see how this implies that the Dehn fillings will give manifolds that differ by mutation on a genus 2 surface (this is the crux of my confusion). From what I can understand, all you've shown is that we can extend the operation of mutating on genus 2 surface from the knot to the Dehn filled manifolds (so this operation is well-defined). This is not the same as proving that the mutation operation commutes with the Dehn filling operation, I don't think.

Comment: @asldjk - Mutation (along a closed genus two surface) does commute with Dehn filling. The operations occur on disjoint submanifolds, so can be performed in either order, yielding homeomorphic manifolds.